# How to query all rows that contain ALL values of a given many to many relation? (Not only one of them!)

Tags: sqlite, relational-division

I've following database structure:

- Table 1: Furniture (Fields: ID)
- Table 2: Material (Fields: ID)
- Table 3: MaterialMatching: (Fields: ID, FK_Furniture, FK_Material)

This structure is able to relate many materials with every furniture...

I know how to query all furniture, that have some special material where the logical relation between the materials is OR:

```
select distinct(furniture.ID) from Furniture 
    left join MaterialMatching ON MaterialMatching.FK_Furniture = Furniture.ID
    left join Material On Material.ID = MaterialMatching.FK_Material
    where Material.ID IN (<< material ids I want to query>>)
```

**Question**

How can I query all furniture that have ALL materials? I want to get all furnitures, that have Material 1 AND Material 2 AND ...

Comment: Actually, I would like to know it for both... But I change it to SQLite as main SQL system...

Comment: you probably added the tag relational-division... With that, I could find a solution...

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a dirty solition but it should solve it. It will return all furniture which has all materials assigned to it

```
select f.* 
from Furniture f
left join (select ftemp.id, count(distinct(mm.FK_Material)) matcount 
           from Furniture ftemp
           left join MaterialMatching mm on mm.FK_Furniture = ftemp.ID
           group by ftemp.id) mmtemp on f.id = mmtemp.id
where mmtemp.matcount = (select count(1) from Material)
```